# How do I render halfspace fog?

Tags: c++, directx, fog

How do I render halfspace fog? From my interpretation, I have a transparent plane in the scene. Then I use a function that returns a fog color in my shader.

Do I render the transparent plane by itself or with the other objects in the scene?
And also, do I make the plane transparent?

Comment: What source are you interpreting? Include a link and we can help you complete your interpretation.

Comment: http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-UnifiedFog.pdf